# yii framework validation error can't show

Tags: php, validation, yii

I modify my department website allow user input author and rank.

But it can't show any validation error message when i type non-integer in rank text.

```
array('dataset_id, author_id, rank', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),

 <?php echo $form->error($model,'rank'); ?>
```

also in controller file when i add

```
    if ($author['rank'] == $rank && $author['name'] == $name) {
                        $model->addError("warning", "Duplicate input");
```

in the view file also can't show any thing, just refresh page blank text Field

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

This is DatasetAuthor model rules

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('dataset_id ,rank,author_name', 'required'),
        array('dataset_id, author_id, rank', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                    // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, dataset_id, author_id, doi_search, author_name_search , orcid_search , rank_search', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Controller function

```
 public function actionCreate1() {
    $model = new DatasetAuthor;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    //this is fake information
    $model->dataset_id = 1;
    //update 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['authors']))
        $_SESSION['authors'] = array();

    $authors = $_SESSION['authors'];

    if (isset($_POST['DatasetAuthor'])) {



        $ranks = trim($_POST['DatasetAuthor']['rank']);
        $names = trim($_POST['DatasetAuthor']['author_name']);
        if (substr($names, -1) == ";")
            $names = substr($names, 0, -1);
        $valid = true;
        $namearray = array();
        if ($names != "")
            $namearray = explode(";", $names);
    //            var_dump($namearray);
        if ($ranks == "")
            $rankarray = array();
        else
            $rankarray = explode(";", $ranks);
    //            var_dump($rankarray);
    //            if (count($namearray) != count($rankarray)) {
    //                $model->addError("error", "the number of name and rank are different!");
    //                $valid = false;
    //            }
        //test names
        if ($valid) {
            foreach ($namearray as $name) {
                if ($name == "") {
                    $model->addError("author_name", "name can't be blank!");
                    $valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //test ranks
        if ($valid) {
            foreach ($rankarray as $rank) {
    //                    if ($rank == "") {
    //                        $model->addError("error", "rank can't be blank!");
    //                        $valid = false;
    //                        break;
    //                    }
                if (!is_numeric($rank)) {
                    $model->addError("rank", "rank should be an integer!");
                    $valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
//            var_dump(count($rankarray)." test");
        if ($valid) {

            foreach ($namearray as $index => $name) {
                if ($index < count($rankarray)) {
                    $rank = $rankarray[$index];
                } else {
                    $rank = 1;

                    while (true) {
                         $found = true;
                        //find the maximum one in the authors array
                        foreach ($authors as $author) {
                            if ($author['rank'] == $rank){
                               $found = false;
                               break;
                            }
                        }
                        if($found)
                            break;

                        $rank++;
                    }


                }

                $valid = true;

                //check if there is duplicate input                 
                foreach ($authors as $key => $author) {
                    if ($author['rank'] == $rank && $author['name'] == $name) {
                        $model->addError("rank", "Duplicate input");
                        $valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ($valid) {

                    //store author dataset
                    $model->rank = $rank;
                    $model->author_name = $name;
                    $id = 0;
                    if ($this->storeAuthor($model, $id)) {

                        $newItem = array('rank' => $rank, 'id' => $id, 'name' => $name);

                        array_push($authors, $newItem);
                        $_SESSION['authors'] = $authors;
                        $vars = array('authors');
                        Dataset::storeSession($vars);
                    } else {
                        $model->addError("error", "database operation failure, please log out first and log in again.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //   $model = new DatasetAuthor;
    $author_model = new CArrayDataProvider($authors);
    $model = new DatasetAuthor;
    $this->render('create1', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'author_model' => $author_model,
    ));
}
```

views

```
        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

          <?= $form->textField($model, 'author_id') ?>

         <?php echo $form->error($model, 'author_id'); ?>

         <?= $form->textField($model, 'rank',array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 200)) ?>
         <?php echo $form->error($model, 'rank'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of [`CModel::addError()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#addError-detail) must be the name of a class attribute. In your case either `name` and/or `rank` will do.

```
if ($author['rank'] == $rank && $author['name'] == $name) {
    $model->addError("rank", "Duplicate input");
```

**UPDATE**

From your controller code, you aren't passing the form data into the model. This is why the fields are blank. Also you aren't calling either `$model->save()` or `$model->validate()` which actually checks against `rules()`. Calling these will remove the need for most of the validity checks you've added in your controller.

```
public function actionCreate1(){
    $model->dataset_id = 1;
    ....
    if(isset($_POST['DatasetAuthor'])){
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['DatasetAuthor']);// pass form data into model
        ....
        if($model->save()){ //calls validate() before saving
            //redirect
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: thanks, but first part array('dataset_id, author_id, rank', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),  <?php echo $form->error($model,'author_id'); ?> why it can't show

Comment: Where is the `array(..)` code located? Also to display the rank error you use `echo $form->error($model,'rank')`

Comment: sorry, it should be <?php echo $form->error($model, 'rank'); ?>. I confused I have set rules in model for rank only integer, but it can't shows any error messages, just refresh page and set text box empty

Comment: Could you include your whole `rules()` and your controller method? You may be unsetting `rank` somewhere.

Comment: As have I with the answer.